# Handing multiple inputs in React with TypeScript 2.0 -> TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string | boolean; }'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I have been reading the guidelines for handing multiple inputs in React.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

The code works but the problem starts with TypeScript. I get the following error for `this.setState({ [name]: value});`:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string | boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IState, "password" | "email">'. Property 'password' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string | boolean; }
```

How can I fix this? I understand that `[name]` is not matched against the state properties but I would like a good solution for it and not a hacking one.

Code:

```
interface IState {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

...

handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}

...

<input
name="email"
type="email"
value={this.state.email}
onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
```

Comment: Try: `const name = target.name as "password" | "email";`

Comment: @NitzanTomer Nope it does not work. I'm thinking of just setting `target.name as any;` since it will do the trick. However since we are using TypeScript I would like to use `any` as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to solve it like this for the time being:

```
const name = target.name as any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const name = target.name as "password" | "email";
const newState: Partial<IState> = {};

newState[name] = value;

this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: Nope this does not work. First error: `newState[name] = value;` -> `error TS2322: Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string'.`
Second error:
`this.setState(newState);` -> `error TS2345: Argument of type 'Partial<IState>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IState, "password" | "email">'. Property 'password' is optional in type 'Partial<IState>' but required in type 'Pick<IState, "password" | "email">'.`

Comment: Right. According to your state interface you always expect a string. but `target.checked` is boolean. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: Image another property for state called `rememberMe` that is a Boolean. Since inputs can be Boolean's as well the generic `handleChange` needs to have it.

Comment: I see. Then if you want to have type safety you'll need to do things a bit differently. For example, you can have different `handleChange` methods for string inputs and boolean inputs. You can of course just go with `any`.